# Would installing Windows 8 be better than System Reset

Tags: windows-8, operating-systems, system-restore

I'm trying to fix a fairly new windows 8 system, it has crashed from what seemed a windows system corruption. I tried doing a system reset, it worked fine then i gave it back to the owner. Again it is not booting correctly and it is giving me advanced troubleshooting options. I have a feeling that the recovery or system reset portion is corrupted. Would wiping the drive and re-installing with a Windows 8 be a reasonable attempt. Keep in mind the current recovery and refresh options have Sony bloatware software and drivers installed. I don't think it is a hard drive issue because it is giving me repair options.

Comment: If a system reset didn't fix the problem, its unlikely, installing WIndows 8 again will fix the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I have had an issue like this before, but it was with a Windows 7 laptop. The first time, the computer fixed itself in recovery, the second time recovery didn't work. After running chkdsk from another computer on the hard drive, the issue was fixed. I thought at this point that the user had been holding down the power button to shut it off or the power cord was coming lose (the battery couldn't old it's charge), which could cause corruption of Windows if this happens at the wrong time. After a while of working on the laptop, I noticed a single "tick" noise every 20 minutes or so. After this, I assumed it was a hard drive malfunctioning. After swapping out the hard drive, and battery (the client wanted a new battery so they didn't have to rely on the power cord) the computer worked fine. It has been about five months since I worked on that computer and the client still is not having issues. The timing between the two events was about a week.

I would try running some hard drive tests on it. Also, ensure that the user is not abruptly shutting the computer off. Another potential problem is a short in the power. Some of the engineers at my work were telling me that the battery could be shorting out if it is a bad battery, causing similar issues. If the battery can hold a change, I wouldn't think this is an issue, but that is assuming this is a laptop.

You are saying that this has Windows 8 on it, so is it fairly new? If so, it might still be under warranty. You may want to engage the manufacturer.

Please post the issue once you find it!